# Printing from different class

Tags: python, class

I've searched for similar questions, and have not found anything. 
Apparently  because my question is pretty basic, yet I find it hard to understand.

I have a class named Student. In this class I get a name of student, and his grades then calculate his average grade. That one was easy, of course.
Here's what I've succeed so far:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, grades_list):
        self.name = name
        self.grades_list = grades_list

    def get_grade_avg(self):
        avg = sum(self.grades_list) / len(self.grades_list)
        return avg

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
```

From the previous part I have:

```
john = Student("John", [100, 90 ,95])
```

Now I need to answer the following qeustion:

Write a class ClassRoom which has a constructor that receives a list of type Student, and saves this list to a member. The following should create a class room:

```
class_room = ClassRoom([John])
```

Implement class ClassRoom such that when calling print(class_room) on a ClassRoom type prints a list of tuples of student name and student grade average, in that order.

Calling print(class_room) should output:

```
[('John', 95)]
```

How do I do it?

I'm very new to OOP and have no idea even how to start.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad as it is, as it basically asks us to do all the work for you. Could you share what you already tried and where exactly you got stuck?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Basically, I forgot I need to add str() in order to print it out. You're right, I should have post it also. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```py
class Student:
    ...
    def __repr__(self):
        return str((self.name, self.get_grade_avg()))


class ClassRoom:
    def __init__(self, students):
        self.students = students

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.students)

john = Student("John", [100, 90 ,95])
mike = Student("Mike", [90, 80, 85])
c = ClassRoom([john, mike])
print(c)

# [('John', 95.0), ('Mike', 85.0)]
print(c)
```

When you call `print` on some object its `__str__` method is invoked and if it is not defined `__repr__` is called. By default `__repr__` of some object is something like this: `<__main__.Student object at 0x7f4b35a3a630>`

In the above code a `Student` *knows* how to show itself, (name, avg), so you can print it if you like: `print(john)`

And for your `ClassRoom`, you just need to override `__str__` to show the student list. Since every student knows how to show itself, it will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add **str**() function to both class and student classes. **str**() if class should iterate over the list of students and print them on by one.